# HTML how do I use the data from a google spreadsheet as my data table for a dashboard?

Tags: html, google-sheets, google-visualization

Do I need to make a function to query the spreadsheet then send it to the dashboard or can I do it within the function that creates the dashboard?

Below is what I've tried and failed at horribly. I've tried other options but this is my most recent so its neither my best nor my worst. How do I use the spreadsheet as my data table for the dashboard and charts?

```
<html>

<head>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

  google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart', 'controls']});
  google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawDashboard);

  function getData (){
    var query = new google.visualization.Query('https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Yjg20TA_quJXDs1ATAjoKkMgYaTSkfm3PXJAou7gf-Y/edit#gid=0');
    return query.getDataTable();
  }

  function drawDashboard() {

    var data = getData();

    var dashboard = new google.visualization.Dashboard(
        document.getElementById('dashboard_div'));

    var varSlider = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
        'controlType' : 'NumberRangeFilter',
        'containerId' : 'filter_div',
        'options' : {
            'filterColumnLabel' : 'random label'}
    });

    var pieChart = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
        'chartType' : 'PieChart',
        'containerId' : 'chart_div',
        'options' : {
            'width' : 300,
            'height' : 300,
            'pieSliceText' : 'value'
            'legend' : 'right'
        }
    });
    dashboard.bind(varSlider, PieChart);
    dashboard.draw(data);
  }

</script>
</head>

<body>
<!--Div that will hold the dashboard-->
 <div id="dashboard_div">
  <!--Divs that will hold each control and chart-->
  <div id="chart_div"></div>
  <div id="filter_div"></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: send the query first, then draw the dashboard, check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42335062/5090771)...

Comment: thank you, I will try this and see if I can get it to work